# Python - Remove words from variable

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace

I am trying to remove any occurrence of 'Doctor', 'Honorable', and 'Professor' from a variable in a dataframe. Here is an example of the dataframe:

| Name |
| --- |
| professor Rick Smith |
| Mark M. Tarleton |
| Doctor Charles M. Alexander |
| Professor doctor Todd Mckenzie |
| Carl L. Darla |
| Honorable Billy Darlington |

Observations could have multiple, one, or none of: 'Doctor', 'Honorable', or 'Professor'. Also, the terms could be upper case or lower case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
regex = '(?:Doctor|Honorable|Professor)\s*'

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(regex, '', regex=True, case=False)
```

Output:

```
                   Name
0            Rick Smith
1      Mark M. Tarleton
2  Charles M. Alexander
3         Todd Mckenzie
4         Carl L. Darla
5      Billy Darlington
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQUAUU/1)

Comment: This worked really well! Could you explain what each line of code is doing?

Comment: This defines a [regex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match any of the three words with optional spaces afterwards and replace them with the empty string. I added a link that explains how this regex works.